# Can we force the SharePoint Lookup field to be delegable inside Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

We have a list named Large123, and inside another list we define a lookup field named ll to reference the Large123 list, as follow:

[image]

but when we try to do a Lookup formula on the Lookup SharePoint field inside our Power Apps, we always get Delegation warning, as follow:

[image]

but if we change the formula to be as follow, the delegation warning will get disappeared:

[image]

So can anyone advice on this? why one formula raised a delegation warning while the other did not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue related to Power apps delegation and SharePoint lookup columns. Delegation only works with the lookup value (column selected under "In this column" option in lookup settings). The additional (extended) columns are not supported in delegation.

[image]

**Similar threads/Source**:

1. [Delegation warning on SharePoint list lookup column .Id versus .Value](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Delegation-warning-on-SharePoint-list-lookup-column-Id-versus/td-p/369410)
2. [SharePoint Lookup Column Id Subfield - Filter Gallery Items - Delegation Warning](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Pro-Dev-ISV/SharePoint-Lookup-Column-Id-Subfield-Filter-Gallery-Items/td-p/654810)

**Documentation**: [Power Apps delegable functions and operations for SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#power-apps-delegable-functions-and-operations-for-sharepoint)

Comment: thanks for the info,, so documentation such as the one on this link https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Community-Blog/The-Ten-Commandments-of-SharePoint-in-PowerApps/ba-p/848842 ,, which mentioned to use numeric fields instead of lookup fields is not 100% correct?

Comment: This approach also works if you are adding/updating data to child list using powerapp/any other automation. But, if users are adding data to child list manually, they have to go to parent list, note ID column, go to child list & then add ID to parentID column in child list manually.