# Is there a way to make our SharePoint Lookup fields delegable inside Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I read many articles about how to make SharePoint lookup field delegable inside SharePoint/PowerApps. and seems if we use `.Value` instead of `.Id` for the lookup we can have delegable filtering. but one article which confused my is this question [Can we force the SharePoint Lookup field to be delegable inside Power Apps](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303397/can-we-force-the-sharepoint-lookup-field-to-be-delegable-inside-power-apps) where in the accepted answer the user provided this image:

[image]

So is this picture correct or wrong? as based on my test the `.Value` on the column under "In this column" is delegable unlike what the image is showing, am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Apps delegation supports SharePoint lookup columns with the primary lookup value (column selected under **In this column** option in lookup settings).

The additional (extended) columns/fields under lookup column settings are not supported in Power Apps delegation.

Image should be read as follows:

1. Delegation **supported** on `.Value` for - primary column selected under **In this column** option
2. Delegation **not supported** on `.Value` (or `.AdditionalColumnName`) for - additional (extended) columns/fields under lookup column settings.

Comment: ok thanks for the great explanation and reply .. so inside the image when it says "no delegation on .value" under additional columns then means the additional columns are not delegable? am i correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. No delegation *support* on `.value` for additional columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a workaround that enables more delegable referencing of various lookup fields: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Community-App-Samples/Large-SP-List-Delegation-Workaround-App/td-p/2330721

It leverages the SharePoint HTTP action & parallel processing in a flow to pull in all the relevant data, including lookups, and passes all that data to the app so it can form a table with it. Then one can use references to the table data for any previously non-delegable operations

Comment: This set-up & explanation includes several screenshots & more characters than what can be included in a stack overflow post. Do not delete for trivial reasons.